# APK crash after converting with Buildozer

Tags: kivy, apk, kivymd, buildozer, requirements

After I convert Python To APK using Buildozer my APK file crashes
is there something wrong in my requirements line
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,psutil,speedtest,pillow

```
import datetime
import threading
import random
from time import sleep
import psutil
import speedtest
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from get_size import get_size
from get_size_bits import get_size_bits
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem, TwoLineListItem, MDList
```

Comment: Have you checked the crash log, there should be some kind of hint what is the problem.

Comment: I don't know how to check it, can you tell me how ? and I am using google collab

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADB to debug your APK file and see what is causing it to crash.

Android Debug Bridge is a tool that helps you debug Android based devices. The daemon on the Android device connects to the server on the host PC via USB.

You need to enable USB debugging on your Android device if you want to connect it to a computer and use it for development purposes. To do this, you need to enter the "Developer Settings" window and enable the USB debugging option. Once you have done this, you can connect your Android device to your computer using a USB cable.

Comment: and from where can I install ADB?

Comment: I did it from here http://www.mediafire.com/file/olujntt4ioezq48/ADB_Intaller.exe/file. Once you have downloaded it and connected your phone in debugging mode you can use the `adb devices` command to check if your device is connected correctly.

Answer (score 0):

According to buildozer documentation you can use

```
buildozer android deploy run logcat
```

this command can help you directly deploy to the android device and see the logcat in order to see what is crashing. Read all details [here](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#run-my-application).

Additionally, buildozer is based on python for android so you can also see if any of that troubleshooting help you to identify the crash
https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting/